# controller action with different render view base on contest page

Tags: yii2

I have a controller action that get called in different places in my app. 
Is it possible to render different view based on caller page?

```
public function actionMyaction($id){

   // blar, blar

   if (/* if I'm calling this action from index */) {
       return $this->redirect(['index']);
   }
   else{
       return $this->redirect(['update']);
   }

}
```

Comment: Possible.. But you have to share your code.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post. :)

Comment: show which condition to redirect or full code. You are on right way.

Comment: Well, the action can be called from "update" page or "index" page, so I just need to get which page is calling the action but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: you want to `render `or `redirect`? What is your `if` condition?

Comment: redirect in this case

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92493/discussion-between-incognito-skulll-and-alecat83).

Answer (score 0):

Try something like,

```
if($model->isNewRecord) 
  return $this->render('create', ['model' => $model]);  
else
  return $this->render('update', ['model' => $model]);
```

Comment: well, in my case this will not work because I use the action in "index" and "update" page so the "model->isNewRecord will always return false.

Comment: it's just an example.. it can be any condition.

Comment: is there a way to retrive the view's name from where the call to the action start?

Comment: you can pass the url to the view to redirect to particular view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, by "caller page" I assume you mean the referrer.

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {

    private function handleRedirect() {
        $referrer = $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
        if (!empty($referrer)) {
            switch ($referrer) {
                case "blar": return $this->redirect("blar");
            }
        }
        $this->redirect("foo");
    }
    public function actionMyaction() {
        // ... blar
        return $this->handleRedirect();
    }

}
```

If not, then maybe you mean the action is the differentiator:

```
class ExampleController extends Controller {

    private function handleRedirect() {
        switch (\Yii::$app->controller->action->id) {
                case "myaction": return $this->redirect("blar");
            }
        $this->redirect("foo");
    }
    public function actionMyaction() {
        // ... blar
        return $this->handleRedirect();
    }

}
```

If not again then please clarify your question!

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
$this->redirect(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

or:

```
$this->goBack(Yii::$app->request->referrer);
```

As per the PHP documentation, $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"] is not always to be trusted:

[PHP $_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Edit: of course, you get the added benefit that the Yii team can actually spell "referrer", and your brain doesn't have to scream about the mis-spelt HTTP version.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need something like this:

```
public function actionMyaction($id){

   // blar, blar

    $referrer = Yii::$app->request->referrer;
    $action = explode('/', $referrer);

        switch (end($action)) {
            case 'index':
                return $this->redirect(['index']);
                break;

            case 'update':
                return $this->redirect(['update']);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
}
```